# Удаление элемента

Tags: javascript

Реализовал создание блоков на js (естественно не сохраняется) и так же как советовали здесь (Doofy) отключил события `pointer-events:none;` но с помощью `after` создал кнопку при клике на который блок должен удалится , но любой код приводит к провалу , помогите разобраться (осваиваю js), код:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <style>
           #createJavaScript{
               width:300px;
               height:200px;
               background:#cc0000;
               float:left;
               margin:2px;
               position:relative;
               pointer-events:none;
               padding:5px;
           }
           #createJavaScript:after{
               content:"Удалить";
               display:block;
               position:absolute;
               right:5px;
               top:5px;
               color:#fff;
               pointer-events:all;
               cursor:pointer;
           }
           #createJavaScript:hover:after{
               content:"Удалить блок";
           }
           #elem{
               position:absolute;
               top:10px;
               left:20px;
           }
           .myButton{
               width:100%;
               height:40px;
               margin:20px 0;
               border:1px solid #cc0000;
               position:relative;
           }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="myButton">
       <button id="elem" type="button " onclick="myFunction()">Создать блок</button>
    </div>

       <script>

            elem.onclick = function(myFunction) { 
                  var oDiv = document.createElement("DIV");
                    oDiv.id = "createJavaScript";
                    var oText = document.createTextNode("Блок создан через JavaScript");
                    oDiv.appendChild(oText);
                    document.body.appendChild(oDiv);
            };
            </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Код 100% рабочий , как реализовать удаление созданного на js (не jquery) ,блока при клике на его `after` на javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Аналог jquery `.on()` на js. По клику на документ ищем элемент, если найден и кликнут, делаем с ним что нужно

```js
document.onclick = function() {
  div = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.createJavaScript'));
  div.forEach((e) => { e.onclick = function() { this.remove(); } });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <style>
           .createJavaScript{
               width:300px;
               height:200px;
               background:#cc0000;
               float:left;
               margin:2px;
               position:relative;
               pointer-events:none;
               padding:5px;
           }
           .createJavaScript:after{
               content:"Удалить";
               display:block;
               position:absolute;
               right:5px;
               top:5px;
               color:#fff;
               pointer-events:all;
               cursor:pointer;
           }
           .createJavaScript:hover:after{
               content:"Удалить блок";
           }
           #elem{
               position:absolute;
               top:10px;
               left:20px;
           }
           .myButton{
               width:100%;
               height:40px;
               margin:20px 0;
               border:1px solid #cc0000;
               position:relative;
           }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="myButton">
       <button id="elem" type="button " onclick="myFunction()">Создать блок</button>
    </div>

       <script>
         elem.onclick = function(myFunction) {
           var oDiv = document.createElement("DIV");
           oDiv.className = "createJavaScript";
           var oText = document.createTextNode("Блок создан через JavaScript" + Math.random());
           oDiv.appendChild(oText);
           document.body.appendChild(oDiv);
         };
      </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Doofy не пашет , вообще + вообще за то что мучаешься со мной

Comment: @Geyan, как не пашет? Жму создать блок - создаётся, жму удалить блок - удаляется

Comment: @Geyan, может я что не понял и надо по "удалить блок" удалить "Создать блок"?

Comment: я смотрю в сниппете и жму удалить не удаляется , могу видео показать даже

Comment: @Geyan, какой браузер и что консоль говорит? [БДЫЩЬ](http://i.stack.imgur.com/XCcet.gif)

Comment: ОС Linux Ubuntu , Google Chrome 51 ..  , пример Алексея Шиманского работает но закрывает не те блоки на которых происходит событие **click**

Comment: @Geyan, А у нас винда. Какие блоки закрываются и какие нужно закрывать? Можно и видос/гифку

Comment: вот видео : https://cloud.mail.ru/public/9HYq/jKhnaMDKo

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42724/discussion-between-geyan-and-doofy).

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте как обычно: навесить слушателя на вновь создаваемый элемент:

```js
var count = 1;
elem.onclick = function(myFunction) {
  var oDiv = document.createElement("DIV");
  oDiv.id = "createJavaScript_"+count;
  oDiv.className = "createJavaScriptClass";
  var oText = document.createTextNode("Блок создан через JavaScript" + count);
  oDiv.appendChild(oText);
  document.body.appendChild(oDiv);

  oDiv.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    document.body.removeChild(this);
  });
  
  count++;
};
```

```css
.createJavaScriptClass {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #cc0000;
  float: left;
  margin: 2px;
  position: relative;
  pointer-events: none;
  padding: 5px;
}
.createJavaScriptClass:after {
  content: "Удалить";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  pointer-events: all;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.createJavaScriptClass:hover:after {
  content: "Удалить блок";
}
#elem {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 20px;
}
.myButton {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 20px 0;
  border: 1px solid #cc0000;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="myButton">
  <button id="elem" type="button " onclick="myFunction()">Создать блок</button>
</div>
```

Удалять в итоге надо будет с того элемента, куда добавили. В данном примере это `document.body`. Соответственно, если будете добавлять элемент в другой место, нужно значит будет потом указать именно его, в качестве объекта, откуда удалять.

Comment: Алексей а если по клику на сам блок ?

Comment: @Geyan убрать `pointer-events: none` у блока видимо.

Comment: Алексей , я не про это , а про то что тыкая на закрыть - закрывается вообще другой блок а не тот на который происходит **click**

Comment: @Geyan вы что-то путаете. я добавил  в код специально дополнительную переменную, чтоб вы видели, что происходит удаление именно того блока, на который кликнули. Либо вы утаили какую-то информацию...... Плюс если блоков много, то вместо id надо юзать класс или присваивать свои айдишники и всё......я это на всякий случай тоже показал в коде..... присвоил классы и в css тоже назначил свойства на классы......... так что ничего в коде не поменялось по сути...и это проще, чем Doofy предлагает в цикле по всем неимоверным элементам бегать